# How to represent form fields for `distance` and `time taken` in a marathon report

Tags: forms, formatting

I'm trying to create a form where I have to ask user for `distance` and `time taken`. For simplicity, let's assume that `distance` is in `kilometers` and `time taken` is in `hours:minutes`.

Now, from UX perspective, what is the best way to create a form? Right now, I have numeric text fields for all of them.

To give more context, I'm trying to create a list of people who participated in a marathon and preparing an interface to show reports.

Comment: Maybe adding start/end point and start/end time could be easier than the total? Just a suggestion, I don't know how people normally take account of this data in marathons.

Comment: Yeah, that would make sense. However, usually, they have a tracker on every runner and at the end of the marathon, we have total data pre-computed. Admin of the web-interface is supposed to see that and update it via the form.

Comment: Will numbers vary much from one user to the next one? Will inputs be pre filled or start empty?

Comment: From past data, I think **max** difference in `distance` would be 100 kms and **average** difference for `time taken` would be 3 hours or so.

Comment: Is the marathon always the same to those who you will send the form?

Comment: I'm developing it for a specific marathon. So yeah, for now, it is same. I made up a form myself as the question was asked about two months ago. I'll post an answer with screenshots soon.

Comment: @JoaoCarvalho I have added an answer.

Answer (score 2):

For such marathon results where the number of player are many - the grid system will work better -

[image]

Comment: Yeah, the listing is not a problem. I was looking for solutions for form fields.

Answer (score 1):

for distance try this one[image]

or you can use road[image]

---

for time try this one[image]

Comment: I was actually looking for a solution that defines the form fields.

Answer (score 1):

Requirement:

Marathon is held. About 1000 candidates take part. We have the date and length of marathon. There's a person at the end of the marathon, who records the time taken by the participant. He enters those details in the web application.

Solution:

I needed to build a form that let's the person to add those entries. This is what I came up with. It is not the best of the solutions and has its limitations but it worked quite well for the day.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're taking raw data from trackers and entering it into some other system for display.

Why are you inserting a person fat fingering data into the mix?

Make a program/script/application to convert and upload the data. It will be faster, more accurate, and solves the problem of needing to design a form.

---

If you absolutely must have a person involved, build your form based on the data the person is using.

If the person is looking at output that includes start location, end location, start time, and end time, those should be your fields. If the person is getting a geo coordinate and completion time in milliseconds, that's what the form fields should be. Converting those inputs into the output of the report should be the responsibility of your application.

You're building a super specialized app for a single purpose/event. The KISS principle applies in spades (KISS = Keep It Simple, Stupid).